# CancelListener and DismissListener not working for TimePickerDialog and DatePickerDialog

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Studio. I'm trying to display a time picker and date picker fragment successively so that a user can select a date and time, but I'm having trouble detecting when the cancel button is pressed for either fragment. I've tried `.setOnCancelListener` and `.setOnDismissListener`, but neither of the two works when the cancel button is pressed. The Log message is never displayed. No error message is given or anything, just nothing happens. Not sure what the issue is, I have tried everything I could find online but to no result. The code setting the not-working listener is here:

```
DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
dateDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
dateDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
      // If the user presses cancel when selecting the date
      Log.i("BlockButton", "Date Dialog cancelled"); // This log message is never displayed
      SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
      SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sharedPref.edit();
      prefsEditor.putBoolean("dateSelected", false); // This SharedPreference isn't changed either
      prefsEditor.apply();
   }
});
```

And the code calling calling the fragment is here:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

It's pretty much the same thing for the TimePicker fragment. What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved somewhat by completely avoiding the problem. Since the `.setOnDismissListener` and `.setOnCancelListener` didn't work, what I did instead was I created a variable set to `false` by default. Then, only if the OK button were pressed at the end of the fragment would the variable be set to `true`. In this way, if the fragment is dismissed and the variable is still equal to false, then we know the Cancel button was pressed.

Hope this makes sense.